# Train score is very lower than Test score, is that normal?

Tags: random-forest, smote, score

I am working on very imbalanced dataset, I used **SMOTEENN** (SMOTE+ENN) to rebalance it, the following test is made using `Random Forest Classifier` :

My train and Test score before using `SMOTEENN`:

```
print('Train Score: ', rf_clf.score(x_train, y_train))
print('Test Score: ', rf_clf.score(x_test, y_test))
Train Score: 0.92
Test Score: 0.91
```

After using `SMOTEEN` :

```
print('Train Score: ', rf_clf.score(x_train, y_train))
print('Test Score: ', rf_clf.score(x_test, y_test))
Train Score: 0.49
Test Score: 0.85
```

**Edit**

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(feats,targ,test_size=0.3,random_state=47)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
scaler_x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)
X = scaler_x_train
y = y_train.values

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.under_sampling import EditedNearestNeighbours
from imblearn.combine import SMOTEENN
   
oversample = SMOTEENN(random_state=101,smote=SMOTE(),enn=EditedNearestNeighbours(sampling_strategy='majority'))
start = time.time()
X, y = oversample.fit_resample(X, y)
stop = time.time()
print(f"Training time: {stop - start}s")

rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, class_weight='balanced', criterion='entropy', random_state= 0, verbose= 1, max_depth=2)
rf_mod = OneVsRestClassifier(rf_model)
rf_mod.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: it might depend on train_test_split and how this was done before and after SMOTENN. Try different splits

Comment: test_size=0.3, and the score before SMOTTEEN was good :                                            
                             Train score: 0.92  and  Test score: 0.91

Comment: how do you use SMOTEENN and how do you train test split? please explain these steps in detail

Comment: @NikosM. I edited it

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not applying the same resampling technique to test dataset. If you put the logic into a imbalanced-learn's [Pipeline](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline), the appropriate resampling will be automatically handled for you.

Comment: I used SMOTEENN only for Train set. See the discussion in link : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15630/train-test-split-after-perform-smote

Comment: I too think splitting and **then** resampling only on train set should be performed (agree with the linked post).